# Access latest entry of name X in CSV file

Tags: python, csv

I have a csv file, the columns are:

```
Date,Time,Spread,Result,Direction,Entry,TP,SL,Bal
```

And typical entries would look like:

```
16/07/21,01:25:05,N/A,No Id,Null,N/A,N/A,N/A,N/A
16/07/21,01:30:06,N/A,No Id,Null,N/A,N/A,N/A,N/A
16/07/21,01:35:05,8.06,Did not qualify,Long,N/A,N/A,N/A,N/A
16/07/21,01:38:20,6.61,Trade,Long,1906.03,1912.6440000000002,1900.0,1000.0
16/07/21,01:41:06,N/A,No Id,Null,N/A,N/A,N/A,N/A
```

How would I access the latest entry where the `Result` column entry is equal to `Trade` preferably without looping through the whole file?

If it must be a loop, it would have to loop backwards from latest to earliest because it is a large csv file.

Comment: Do you use pandas?

Comment: @U11-Forward No this is just using the built in CSV module, but if I have to use pandas for this solution thats not an issue, but I assume that it should be achievable without it?

Comment: It would be more efficient and cleaner with pandas...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use `pandas`, try using `read_csv` with `loc`:

```
df = pd.read_csv('yourcsv.csv')
print(df.loc[df['Result'] == 'Trade'].iloc[[-1]])
```

Answer (score 1):

Load your .csv into a pd.DataFrame and you can get all the rows where `df.Results` equals `Trade` like this:

```
df[df.Result == 'Trade']
```

if you only want the last one then list use .iloc

```
df[df.Result == 'Trade'].iloc[-1]
```

I hope this is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you use `pandas`, but in case you really cannot, here's an approach.

Assuming the data is in `data.csv`:

```
from csv import reader

with open("data.csv") as data: 
     rows = [row for row in reader(data)]

col = rows[0].index('Result')
res = [row for i, row in enumerate(rows) if i > 0 and row[col] == 'Trade']
```

I advise against using this, way too brittle.